# slicing rows and put back in as variables in R

Tags: r, slice, reshape

I want to slice a few rows and add the data back into the dataset as another variable. so my task goes like this... converting

```
location   year   value
aus       1990    1
aus       1991    2
aus       1992    2
usa       1990    1
usa       1991    3
usa       1992    2
uk        1990    3
uk        1991    2
uk        1992    2   
...     

into something like this

year   value_aus   value_usa   value_uk
1990      1            1          3
1991      2            3          2
1992      2            2          2
.
.
.
```

my data have 56 years for 36 different countries.

I tried as follows..

```
nations<-factor(data$LOCATION)
nationlist<-nations[!duplicated(nations)]


data_w<-data.frame(year=data$TIME[data$LOCATION==nationlist[1]])

for(loc in c(as.character(nationlist))){
  data_w<-data.frame(data_w[,], loc = data$Value[data$LOCATION==loc], check.rows=TRUE)
  }
```

but this didn't work and spits out "arguments imply differing number of rows: 56, 54" as some of the countries have different number of observations(years in this case) i guess.

Any helps would be greatly appreciated.

Jinseok

Comment: I think It isn't good idea to transform long format into wide format manually. `tidyr::spread(your_data, location, value)` would give what you want (see `help(spread, tidyr)`).

Comment: @cuttlefish44 wow! it works perfectly! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. The key is to use `spread` to convert data frame from long format to wide format. `setNames(sub("location", "value", colnames(.)))`
 is just to change the column names to be the same as the desired output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  spread(location, value, sep = "_") %>%
  setNames(sub("location", "value", colnames(.)))
dt2
#   year value_aus value_uk value_usa
# 1 1990         1        3         1
# 2 1991         2        2         3
# 3 1992         2        2         2
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "location   year   value
aus       1990    1
                 aus       1991    2
                 aus       1992    2
                 usa       1990    1
                 usa       1991    3
                 usa       1992    2
                 uk        1990    3
                 uk        1991    2
                 uk        1992    2   
                 ",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```